# What is the CSS selector for text inside a span?

Tags: html, css

I have two objects inside a span; another span, and some text. It is worth noting that the HTML cannot be changed as it is referenced from another website which is read-only.

I need a CSS selector to reference *just* the text (highlighted in the image below), ignoring the other span — is this possible?

[image]

Comment: CSS selectors reference elements. The text is the content of an element so not something you can grab on its own.

Comment: You can target the inner span and style its text

Comment: So you can't execute JavaScript in that page's context right, your stylesheet only gets loaded there?

Answer (score 3):

It may not be possible, but what possible is, reset the styles of the inner span:

```css
span {font-weight: bold;}
span span {font-weight: normal;}
```

```html
<span>Outside <span>Inside</span> Outside</span>
```

The above code is making the text alone to be bold, technically leaving the inner span.  You just need to reset the styles of inner span, for all those changes you did with outer ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
span{font-size : 15px;} span.comment{font-size:30px;}
```

//The first style block refers to all spans , whereas the second style block refers to the span with the class of comment and overrides the upper style block.